# Error on script to clear cache docker container

Tags: docker

I need to clear cache manually in my nginx docker container and would make a script, i have make a script that found the PID:

```
docker-pid

#!/bin/sh
exec docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' "$@"
```

And another final script

```
clear_cache.sh

#!/bin/sh
PID=/usr/bin/docker-pid proxy_nginx_1
nsenter -m -p -u -n -i -t $PID
rm -rf /etc/nginx/cache/*
exit
```

I get this error:

```
./clear_cache.sh: line 2: proxy_nginx_1: command not found
```

if i launch `docker-pid` to shell, it works....Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash you have to use `$(<COMMAND>)` if you want to save the output of a command to a variable. So

clear_cache.sh

---

```
#!/bin/sh
PID=$(/usr/bin/docker-pid proxy_nginx_1)
nsenter -m -p -u -n -i -t $PID
rm -rf /etc/nginx/cache/*
exit
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
PID=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' "$@")
nsenter -m -p -u -n -i -t $PID
rm -rf /etc/nginx/cache/*
exit
```